# After uninstalling Edubuntu, my dash icon has been replaced by a question mark

Tags: unity-dash, icons

I'm new to Linux. I had no idea that Edubuntu would change as much as it did. I thought it was just a folder with a bunch of apps. Anyway I uninstalled it, but the following command I used (from http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome) took the dash icon away with it. So can anyone tell me how I could just simply reset the dash icon, that would be great.

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server alacarte arkose arkose-gui arkose-nautilus atomix atomix-data avogadro-data blinken blt breathe-icon-theme ca-certificates-java calibre calibre-bin celestia-common celestia-gnome cgroup-lite debootstrap default-jdk default-jre default-jre-headless desktop-profiles dia-common dia-gnome dia-libs docbook-xsl edubuntu-artwork edubuntu-desktop edubuntu-docs edubuntu-fonts edubuntu-menueditor edubuntu-wallpapers freemind freemind-doc gamine gamine-data gcompris gcompris-data gcompris-sound-en geogebra gimp gimp-data gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-fallback gobby-0.5 gobby-infinote gsfonts-x11 human-icon-theme human-theme icc-profiles icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx icedtea-plugin icoutils imagemagick inkscape italc-client italc-master java-common java-wrappers javahelp2 junit kalzium kalzium-data kanagram kate-data katepart kbruch kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdebase-runtime kdeedu-kvtml-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdoctools khangman kig kmplot kolourpaint4 krosspython ktouch ktuberling kturtle kubuntu-debug-installer kwordquiz laby libaccess-bridge-java libaccess-bridge-java-jni libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libart-2.0-2 libattica0 libavogadro1 libbabl-0.0-0 libbackport-util-concurrent-java libbcel-java libblas3gf libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libboost-program-options1.46.1 libboost-python1.46.1 libcdt4 libchm1 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libcommons-codec-java libcommons-math-java libcompoundviewer4 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libdom4j-java libdxflib-2.2.0.0 libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libfparser-4.3 libfreehep-export-java libfreehep-graphics2d-java libfreehep-graphicsio-emf-java libfreehep-graphicsio-java libfreehep-graphicsio-pdf-java libfreehep-graphicsio-svg-java libfreehep-graphicsio-tests-java libfreehep-io-java libfreehep-swing-java libfreehep-util-java libfreehep-xml-java libgc1c2 libgegl-0.0-0 libgetopt-java libgfortran3 libgimp2.0 libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnu-regexp-java libgps19 libgraph4 libgsasl7 libgsl0ldbl libgtkglext1 libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libgvc5 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libice-dev libilmbase6 libinfgtk-0.5-0 libinfinity-0.5-0 libio-socket-ssl-perl libiodbc2 libitalc libjama-java libjas-plotter-java libjaxen-java libjaxme-java libjaxp1.3-java libjcommon-java libjdom1-java libjfreechart-java libjgoodies-forms-java libjibx1.1-java libkabc4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdeedu-data libkdegames5a libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkeduvocdocument4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkunitconversion4 liblapack3gf liblog4j1.2-java liblqr-1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmagick++3 libmagickcore3 libmagickcore3-extra libmagickwand3 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmarblewidget12 libmicroblog4 libmikmod2 libming1 libmono-corlib2.0-cil libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetpbm10 libntlm0 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libopenbabel4 libopenexr6 libopenide-util-java libpanel-applet-4-0 libpathplan4 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpodofo0.9.0 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libprison0 libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqdox-java libqimageblitz4 libqrencode3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4 librecad librecad-data librecad-doc libregexp-java libscience4 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-net1.2 libsdl-pango1 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsm-dev libsmpeg0 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libtablelayout-java libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libwmf-bin libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libwxbase2.6-0 libwxgtk2.6-0 libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomp3 libxdmcp-dev libxerces2-java libxml++2.6-2 libxml2-utils libxom-java libxpp2-java libxpp3-java libxss1 libxt-dev liferea liferea-data lightspeed lmodern luatex lxc lybniz marble marble-data marble-plugins mathpiper melting mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 netpbm ntrack-module-libnl-0 nxproxy odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 opendict openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib otf-freefont oxygen-icon-theme parley parley-data pdfmod pencil perlmagick phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript plymouth-theme-edubuntu python-avogadro python-beautifulsoup python-central python-cherrypy3 python-clientform python-configobj python-cssutils python-cssutils-doc python-django python-django-tagging python-dnspython python-encutils python-gevent python-gmenu python-gnome2 python-greenlet python-kde4 python-lxml python-mechanize python-nautilus python-netaddr python-numpy python-paramiko python-pyorbit python-pyparsing python-pysqlite2 python-qt4 python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-routes python-sip python-tk python-uniconvertor python-webob python-wimpiggy python-wxgtk2.6 python-wxversion python-x2go qapt-batch ri-li ri-li-data rlwrap scribus-ng shared-desktop-ontologies simplyhtml soprano-daemon stellarium stellarium-data step tcl8.5 tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-luatex texlive-xetex tk8.5 ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-baskervald ttf-adf-berenis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-ikarius ttf-adf-irianis ttf-adf-libris ttf-adf-mekanus ttf-adf-oldania ttf-adf-romande ttf-adf-switzera ttf-adf-tribun ttf-adf-universalis ttf-adf-verana ttf-aenigma ttf-ancient-fonts ttf-atarismall ttf-bengali-fonts ttf-beteckna ttf-bpg-georgian-fonts ttf-breip ttf-century-catalogue ttf-dejavu-extra ttf-devanagari-fonts ttf-droid ttf-dustin ttf-ecolier-court ttf-ecolier-lignes-court ttf-engadget ttf-essays1743 ttf-femkeklaver ttf-fifthhorseman-dkg-handwriting ttf-georgewilliams ttf-goudybookletter ttf-gujarati-fonts ttf-inconsolata ttf-isabella ttf-junicode ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-levien-museum ttf-levien-typoscript ttf-linex ttf-linux-libertine ttf-marvosym ttf-mgopen ttf-oflb-asana-math ttf-oflb-euterpe ttf-okolaks ttf-opendin ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-radisnoir ttf-rufscript ttf-sil-andika ttf-sil-doulos ttf-sil-gentium ttf-sjfonts ttf-staypuft ttf-tamil-fonts ttf-telugu-fonts tuxmath tuxpaint tuxpaint-data tuxpaint-plugins-default tuxpaint-stamps-default tuxtype tuxtype-data tzdata-java ubuntu-edu-preschool ubuntu-edu-primary ubuntu-edu-secondary ubuntu-edu-tertiary virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xaos xorg-sgml-doctools xpra xtrans-dev xvfb yorick yorick-data yorick-z && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Used the command from this site:http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Answer (score 1):

Goto the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install unity
```